# Error on getToken() after updating fcm plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, ionic3

I update the **FCM** plugin with cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-update and than getting an Error on getToken()

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Check your project type in the ionic.config.json file.

If the type is **"ionic-angular"**, then install 4.x.x version.

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/firebase@4.20.0
```

If the type is **"angular"**, then install 5.x.x-beta version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/firebase@5.0.0-beta.24
```

**Note**:

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using **Angular 6**

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
```

if not remove **ngx** from the import both in app.module.ts and app.component.ts

```
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
```

[Refencence](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074)

after this, you are getting the issue then feel free to write here.

Comment: When i use import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';
Than getting error 'FCM' refers to a value, But it being used as a type here on public fcm : FCM